# Exploiting "iterate over this layer" option to process polygons within the same layer separately and obtaining a merged final output

Tags: python, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I'd like to merge the outputs of the below script, when run with "iterate over this layer" option. The reason to enable iteration option is not to obtain separate files, but to process each feature in the file within the exact polygon boundary. Otherwise the process gives erroneous results because of boundary interactions. In this regard, I added "Merge Vector Layers" function to the end of the script. However, it still gives separate output files.

Any thoughts on what I am missing?

```
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing, QgsProcessingAlgorithm, QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback, QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource, QgsProcessingParameterNumber, QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink, QgsProcessingParameterField, QgsProperty
import processing

class PolygonSplittingEdited(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource('poligonfeatures', 'Polygon to Split', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue='Polygons'))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterField('numberofparts', 'Number of Parts to Split Polygon', type=QgsProcessingParameterField.Numeric, parentLayerParameterName='poligonfeatures', allowMultiple=False, defaultValue='Divisions'))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('splittedpolygon', 'Splitted Polygon', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(5, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Random points inside polygons
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['poligonfeatures'],
            'MIN_DISTANCE': 0,
            'STRATEGY': 0,
            'VALUE': QgsProperty.fromExpression(parameters['numberofparts']),
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['RandomPointsInsidePolygons'] = processing.run('qgis:randompointsinsidepolygons', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract by location
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': outputs['RandomPointsInsidePolygons']['OUTPUT'],
            'PREDICATE': 0,
            'INTERSECT': parameters['poligonfeatures'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractByLocation'] = processing.run('native:extractbylocation', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(2)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Voronoi polygons
        alg_params = {
            'BUFFER': 200,
            'INPUT':  outputs['ExtractByLocation']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['VoronoiPolygons'] = processing.run('qgis:voronoipolygons', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        
        feedback.setCurrentStep(3)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Intersection
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['poligonfeatures'],
            'INPUT_FIELDS': [''],
            'OVERLAY': outputs['VoronoiPolygons']['OUTPUT'],
            'OVERLAY_FIELDS': [''],
            'OVERLAY_FIELDS_PREFIX': '',
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Intersection'] = processing.run('native:intersection', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
  
        feedback.setCurrentStep(4)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}
            
        # Merge vector layers
        alg_params = {
            'LAYERS': outputs['Intersection']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['splittedpolygon']
        }
        outputs['Final'] = processing.run('native:mergevectorlayers', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['splittedpolygon'] = outputs['Final']['OUTPUT']
        return results
                
    def name(self):
        return 'Polygon Splitting Edited'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'Polygon Subdivider Edited'

    def group(self):
        return 'Polygon Subdivider Edited'

    def groupId(self):
        return 'Polygon Subdivider Edited'

    def createInstance(self):
        return PolygonSplittingEdited()
```

**Simple test data can be reached below:**
https://we.tl/t-TQL1LsxiBl

Comment: What is the code supposed to do / what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The code divides the features in a given layer regarding values of the selected field. If you do that without iteration, the total number of splitted polygons exceed the sum of field values as a result of extra polygons created near the boundaries. I thought, it might be a good idea to perform feature-based subdivision thru iteration and then merge them up. Activating iteration gives correct number of subdivisions, yet I end up with having separate files. In case of thousands of features, creating that much files and merging them manually isn't practical. Hence, I'm trying to automatise it.

Comment: Are you using the modeler?

Comment: Nope, I added the mentioned script into QGIS scripts folder and run it under Processing Toolbox/Scripts.

Comment: I think you should start from zero and use a for loop. Execute the tools manually in QGIS,  with temp outputs press Ctrl+Alt+H to see the correct syntax. Then pass the output of each tool as input to the next (if that is what you want to do). For example `intersection_layer = processing.run("native:intersection", {'INPUT':'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/buildings_con.shp','OVERLAY':'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/buildings_two_groups.shp','INPUT_FIELDS':[],'OVERLAY_FIELDS':[],'OVERLAY_FIELDS_PREFIX':'','OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})['OUTPUT']`. Then append the final results to a list and merge the list

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.